# Can you not sell/destroy buildings?

Tags: civilization-6, civilization-6-gathering-storm

So I've started playing Gathering Storm, built a bunch of coal plants and now Global Warming is out of control mainly because of me. I've been trying to remove these power plants, but I haven't found any option to sell/destroy or even replace these buildings.

Is there seriously no way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are city projects (all the way at the bottom of the production queue) that allow you to **convert** the power plant to another power source, e.g. convert to oil, convert to nuclear, ...

These conversions are unlocked through specific research techs.