# How do I dismantle a power plant?

Tags: civilization-6, civilization-6-gathering-storm

I have several power plants causing pollution. However, the cities they're in have enough clean power sources nearby.

Can I dismantle the dirty power plants in the industrial zones?

Answer (score 0):

There are city projects (all the way at the bottom of the production queue) that allow you to convert the power plant to another power source, e.g. convert to oil, convert to nuclear, ...

These conversions are unlocked through specific research techs.
(( Credit to Flater, previously asked / answered at [Can you not sell/destroy buildings?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/347175/can-you-not-sell-destroy-buildings) ))